# In word embedding, how to map the vector to word?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, word2vec, sequence-to-sequence

I checked all API and couldn't find a way to map vector to word no matter in word2Vec or glove. Google doesn't help that much.

Does anybody know to do this?

Background: I'm training a chatbot by using seq2seq model. But the implementations I found so far are using one-hot encoding. So I want to try use glove embedding and use the output mapping back to the word.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs of your learning architecture will certainly not be identical to vectors of particular words. What you could try would be to find the distance between **each** output vector and **all** vocabulary words, and simply pick the word that minimizes that distance. Don't expect amazing results though; they are using one-hot encodings for a reason.